# debian from disk to big disk: what i miss?

Tags: debian, boot, lvm, initramfs

Usually i migrate virtual machine to new bigger disk
following this procedure

```
a)Attach new disk
b)Mount to mnt
c)rsync -avogpP --delete /olddirs /mnt/newdirs
except for tmp proc sys dev,i use to mount them
with -o bind
d)then i chroot to mnt
```

install lilo,make initrd lilo -v and on reboot all works..
on Slackware.
On Debian i see this problem
lvm is not see from initramfs
on boot i see debian
try to mount with 
a lot of

```
debian scripts/local-block...
```

and then give me to (initramfs) menu
From this i can mount root with

```
lvm pvscan
lvm vgscan
lvm vgchange -ay
```

then i mount /dev/vg0/root /root
and exit and..kernel panic.
What i miss?
Of course i have remake the initramfs with
mkinitramfs -k kernelversion -v
and give lilo -v

This is kernel panic after mount /dev/vg00/root /root

[image]

Comment: What did the kernel panic from? Why did the initramfs fail to bring up LVM (there should be failure messages)? (Side note, why are you still running LILO‽) (Side note 2, if you're using LVM, why don't you move things to new disks using `pvmove`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Solution" found..update to grub
I prefer lilo,but strange doesn't work
with this procedure.